# Fail2ban filter for error 400 on nginx

Tags: nginx, fail2ban, ubuntu-20.04

I have a nginx server I am hosting very base php website (school club) and log file show lot of weird requests how do I block them. I tried using fail2ban but my filters were not accurate.

nginx-400.conf

```
[Definition]
regex = ^<HOST> -.* 400 .*$
```

Logs:-

```
    151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:09 +0530] "-2\xBB\xE4\xF5F" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:11 +0530] "6\xEB\xB0\x10\xB5M\xE2m.\xD0\x93>\xF8\x1B\x82\xD8G2\xA97\xC5" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:12 +0530] "\x08\x15\xA5SW(\x809F\x85v\xFB\x8C\x84\x1Bx\xE6\xD6>\x05\x81\x9C\x12\xF0b<sVx\xF3\xCArP\x80\xBEy\xA1\xAB\xDA\x0B\xE8\xAE\xF0\x86~\x87\x8B\x05\x18\x9Eg\xD5\x99p06\x96\x17\x08\xAB$I\xE1\xB7\x8E\x05=\xE1\x1F\x12O\xA1I\xBC\xF9\x9F\xDA\x08\xB3I\xE6 \x1An|.\xFFB\xE6:N\xB3&\xDB\x82\xD9\xFAF0j\x8B(\x9E\xDA<[2\xA6\xBEN\xB5\xB3\x92\xBET%>\x84?\xF5r" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:12 +0530] "f\x16ch]\xF5\xB5a\x02N\x17\xC6\xB0\xDF\xB8" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:12 +0530] "\x13\x9D\x8D\xA5\xFF\xD9\xF8\x84wi\xFA\xE2\xA0`\x00jc\x5Cr\xFE#\xE3\xDC\xBFO\xF9\xEE\x17\xDE" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:13 +0530] ".\xBC%|t\xCB\x95q\xFBt\xA4\x1D-\xEA\x8A;!\xFE\x1C\x8C4\xA4!\xA7\xEBk4\xD2X\xD9~\xA1\xBE\xFF\xBA\xA8\xD7\x89K\xABSR\x15\x80\xC34zTg6\xEE{nr\xF9\xE6\xBF" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:13 +0530] "\x17\x81\xB7u\x97\x8Fxzs\x88\xBD\x9A\xA3\x86TT\x8F\x1F\x95\xC0\x8C\xE8\x16q;q\xD0\xA6[FU\xD3\xA6ZK\x14\xE1\xBD\xBDX\x02I\xCDRY\xF0\xA2\x13@<\xCB\xF7,\xD9\x81\xD2\xAC\x05\xE9\x9Fn\xE2|\x92" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:14 +0530] "\x04\xAD\xCE\xF2\x0E\x85\xE9\xAF\xA0\xAE\xABS%" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:14 +0530] "hq\x924\xAB\x94\xDCI\x8DmU\x0F\xE3\x93X\xB2\xDA.\x96\xC6\xA6|46\xB9v\xCE\x91W+\x07=\xE1\x81}\xAC\x0C\x8B\xDD\xCDd\x87\x00" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:17 +0530] "M\x8C\xC4*\xF0D\x99\x85\xD8\x88\xCD\x19a\xAF\xEB\xF8\xB2\xEARp\xDF~\x8D\xAD\x8D\xFCPaT\x11\xCB\xA4#\x8CNP\x9E\xF5\xAF\xFD\xEB*j\x00DW\x1A@\xB7\xC8J\xF6\xB1\xBA\xEF\x0CR\xEF\x9AV\x10\xB3W)\xD5\xBB+&\xA0\xC4U\xA3*\xD1\x15\x8A\xCB\xB7\xAD\xC9\xE3l\xD2\xBA!\xFCNY\xA3\xE4\x9EF\x91\xA5\x0B\xFD\x83Hm\xB0<\x9E\x07" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:18 +0530] "H>\xE1s\xA5\x83\xDA\xD7B\x10\x80;A" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:19 +0530] "\x11$nHC\xC5\x86\xF3\xC7;V\x0C\xF0\x93\x91\xAC\xE1\xDE\x1A\xDA\x8E8USx\x14\xF9d\xBB\x99\xEC\xED\x87s\x99\xDA\x80\x9C\x17\xCBP\xAC'\xC8r\xCE\x13\x1F5d\xF6*U\x89t\xCE\xC6\xD0\x1B\x84\x16\x0F\xED\xD8nJ\xAC\xBC\xB6\x02" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:19 +0530] "\x1E\x1EK\xE9\xEFt\xF7\xD0\xA0?\x9B\xEC\xDD\xEFp\x03\x03\xC3\x1F\xD2\xED\xCFK\xB3\xE3{[^i\xBD\xCAe1Db\x8C\xA2\x93\xA2\xE9\xFE!q\x8EI\xB8\xB0\xB1\x81R\x05\xE9F#\xEA\xB30\xE1\xEB\xBA\xC6\x1D\xDC\xAF\xC9l\x950d\x9C\x07\x0F\xE4]\xEEt\x99\x02\xCC\xE7\xD5\x87\x9C\xDA\xDE\xD38r\x8A\x9B\xEA\x83\xAD\xA0\x88\x18\x8B\x0BY\xA4~\x1DYAk\x9A#Q\x85\x0Bj\x98\xA4H/?\x83q\x87)\xF9C\xAE\xD3'U\xB0~4\xBA\xBF\x8A&\x89hX\xB8\xBDz6\xAD\xFC\x16o\x82\xD5\x90\xAB]\xC6G\xFBA\xF2\xCB\x0C\xC87\xEA:>\x8F\x88>2a\x05\xC6\xA2>\xAEf\x00\xFCD\x08\x86\x8BD\xE0;$9%{YP" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:19 +0530] "g\x15I\x1D=q ?\x98\xA2\xDA.\xFA\xCE\x8B\x94\xAE\xDAW\xF6dW\xA4\x9At(\xE2Xi4\x11\x0C\xCB>\xFC\x14\xB7\xD2\xEB#\xBC\xD47LN)\xA2W\x8B\x10\xE0lc<s\x10IO\x89\xBB\xB4H\xAAE\xB8\xB4 \xEE\xCBP\xD0U\xAC\xD8\x06\xDF\xDCv\x1B\x81\x1A\xEB\x88\xD8\xD3 s\x9E1Di\xB1.\xB6\xFA6Q\x9C\x90\x8Cs<\xFB\xF5>u\x1CJw\xF7\xC1:\x9F\x81(\x11ap6Z\xBB\x8A\x9E\xC1\xC7\xBF\xAA1\xB3N]\xE53\xCD\x8F:4B\xEFI\xF6\xFE'[\xB8\xAF.\x84\xDFhF=\xC2\xA1\x16\x95w\xCF%\xCC\xFFw\x89\x10\x9D\xB0b9\x12\x9D\xEEGs\x1B@`\xB0\xF5\x1D\xDF\xC38S\x1A\xA7J+\xF5\xF4\xC6\xE9\x83z\x10\xC1S\x836\xC0\xA3\x05\x88>?8\x0B\x06\x94&a\xED\x9B\xB4W\x1D\x84\x8E\x13\xF4\xB0NR\x87\x14a~\xC9\x93\xD8-\x82M\xCA\x97\xE0\xD3\xB8UK\xBD\xD4s\xF2\xFE\x960\xCA\x9D\xDC%\xC8P\xB1nP\xEB<\xDB\x97\xCDx\x97\xC7\xDC4ZL\x88\x94\xF6\x81\xAA\xCD\xE6\xDFc\x90\xB2\x07\x85\x1B]\x87S\xFE\xA8\xAFz\xBB\x83\xCB+\xD2\xF3\x87\xF6\x8A\xD6\xA08\xBA\xB3\x00\x1B`\xFFq\xAC\x91/7~\x93j \x00f\xB2\x14\xDCH\x99\xC4.Z\xC7\x22\x22M\xE9\xD9N\x1CZ{\xD6p:\xD9\xCBW\x09\xBE)\x84" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:20 +0530] "]\xEC\x02\xC1\x00\xF0\xB8Y\xE4\xE9" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:20 +0530] "X\xBCx\xA3\xBB\xFEc\x0CE\xD5\xB5\xE4\x86\x02\xDABE\x1B\x0E\xB8\xCC\x95\xBDp" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:20 +0530] "H]\xCF=r'\x15\xD7\xA2|8+\xEC\x14\xA2\xB5\xF5\x07\xC8\xAEm}\x82" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:21 +0530] ":\xA7RZ$\x95~Yo0\x80o7T" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:23 +0530] "\x13\xA6\x8Ei" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:23 +0530] "i\xF5\x9F\xB8@\x15\xAE\xE8b\xEF\x80@\x86\x5ClS}\xBC\x86Y\xD9\xC6\x05\x8C\x0B\x99N\xF1\xA4\x09G\xE4\xBD\xD3\xEF\x14\x005\xE4\xEC\x5C\x86\xA8-\xCF\xE4|2\xB2\xBE\x97\x7F\x135)\xAA\xC0\xBB'\xB6\x92\xAC\x9Dd\x87\xE6\xA2\x09\xF3\x91\x0BX\x00\xD2x7\xBD\x83\xABJ\xDC\x05\x08\x89'\xCA3g,\x14\x04\x1B\x1A\xE1\x1A\x9D\xBC\xF9\xA3\x84\x0EGq\x81%r\xFEX\xB71\xEC\x13\x16)\x80H\xEEo\xD4'\xF8\xCA\xDB\x9Bx\x1Ex\x07\xB7\xA6\x82\x15x\x1B\xF9U\xB9\x91\x1Ay\xF2oo\xB3\x86SP\xBFt\xF3\x17\x91>\xD8B\x9DM\x83f\x13\x8F\xFB\xC7@\x7F\xB1\xCF\xC90\xCCy\xE2\xFA3\xB7,08\x99\xA3r\xE1\x09\x12e\xEE.\x94\x98\xE8;i" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:26 +0530] "\x03;z\xF3\xAC\x85`[\xE7\x99" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:26 +0530] "w\xCA<\xC6p\x80\x86|+\xDD\x1A\xB7%\x08\x03\x07\x8E\xC7\xF6\x89O&Fl\xF3\x13\xD0\xDF?\x03\x05\xEC\x5C\xB7\xAD<\xD3Z:\x90$\x8D\xB6\xC7\xF0\xB61\x90A\xE0\x81%iE\xE9c\xB6\x9F\xB6v\xE2\x0E\xA9G\xBD\xE6\xB7\xA6\x00\x19\x993\xCCR\xA1\xAEs\xD9v\xBCMw\xC0\xBDv\xFC\x02Eg\xD0\x18\x89\x15\xAE\x1Fn\x01E\xF2\x8F\x907:\xD30\x9A\xB1\xFEP\xF1G\xB6\xE0\x86\xA6\xDB\xE8\xA7\xDEA\x15&\xA7 \x01\x81\xF3\xE7\xAF\xD7\x8F\xE6\xB7\x80,\xD1`\xF8\x09\xFD\xB1\x85D\xC1\x828\x5C\xCCT\xED\x95@W" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:26 +0530] "Q\x17\xDCKn\xC3\x01\x13\xCD\xDC\x8B\x84\xF6S\xCAs9\x93_\xF6=\xA7\x1D.i^d\xB5\xB9V\xEA\x1E\xB3!}\xDE\xA6\x07\xBC\x9B\xDA\xC4[q\xDC\xBD\x0C\x18\x11\xD3\x91\xA8\x05\xA7\x0E\x13K\x8A\xB6\xC9\xA3hp\x9A\x87\xD8sS\xF3\xFF\xC8b\xDFz\xC5aY\xD6q\x8E\x05\x9A\x91/\x98-\x9A\xFCl\x8F\xC1,\xA1W\x8Dq0\xE6\x97x\xDE\x03\x1A\xD4,\xFC\x90\x22\xAFG\x8E\xAC\x86)\xCBE\xEC;'\xFA\x80\x11\x8F\x15\xE1\xEB\xE4\x04V\x9E\xD6\xAE\x869\x99\x91\x13\x11\x98\xBF\xA1b\x9B\xD2>\x06\xDE\xE2\xB3f\x92\x98\xDB\xDD\x93\xBE\xF7\xBE\xEF.\xFE\x94\xAC\x9A2\xB5x=\x8Fwi\x8F\xD7N#\xE1F\xA5\xA9\xC1sl0=\xC4\x95Z\xBA:\xD4\x85\xE19\x02\x9B:\x0FlcL\x1C\xFBN\x9D\xF4\xF5\xF8L\xD0\x8D\x08\xC5*i\x97F\x92{k\x93)\x90\xAB\xCB\xC0K3\xD0\x1E\xEB5\x14\x16OC\xC2\xFB\x18\xAF\xC4xf=B\xC1\xD8\xF4\xDB\x12A\x9AT\x17\x18C\x1E{\xDD\x14g[\xEC_\x0B\x5C\x13?\xF7{PP\x973\xE3WuD'\xF2\x92\xD45\xC0\xBB\x00nK\xB8\x8Ed\x02\xA23\xA3\xAA\xC6pP~u\x04x\xE7\xC5\x90\xE0\xE9\x10\x10\x7F\xCEu\xEAR\xD6WTC\xCDV\x1AB\xC2-\xCC\x9E\xA6-\x1A" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:28 +0530] "k\x9E\x93\x13{;\xCA%\xBDt\xF2\x83\x1A\x82\xC7Z\xB3\xEDL;9\xC8\xB9\x8D\xEC\xA5\x08\xB2\xF0\xCC\x16&\x09r\x1F\xE1\x1F\xA0V(\x1FY\xC8\xAC=>\xF2\xF7\x8A\xA7\x7F\x1B>\x93\xB8\xDB\x8C\xE5\x12\xBC@\xFD\x8DmQ\x84)'0wko;cH\xF8\xF8\x95\x885\xA1\xC7\x14 \xC0!\x90o\xC9R!\xC38J1o\xB8\xCAfF\x99Z\xD1\x9E\xAB&\xF7\xCE6\xCE\xFE6\xB9\xCC\x85\xA3\xF6\x14\x09\xDD\xBE\x19\x05\xB9\xEC\x17\xEC\xC7\xB2X\xC2\xEA\xEA#1\x88\xAB\xEA\x8B\xB6\x89\xB9\xCC6\x85\xFE\x18\xE9\xFD\xB4\xA48pR\xB2\x0CA\x97B|1" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:40 +0530] "Y\xA8\xCD\xC5\xB5'\xC6o\xEEL\xEF\xDA\xDA\xEA>(" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:41 +0530] "H\xD0\xD7\xB4\x14lR\xF3\x1D\xFA\xB4O\x98\xB9\xB0\x840K\xA3\x03\xF5NA\xB1Yv\x17\xF0\x13H\x10\xA0\xE6\xDBT\x04\xBF\xA1\xDB&\x1Du\xE8\xB4\x9B\x95(\x9EA\xC0t\x12K{ih" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:41 +0530] "\x1A[\xEA" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:44 +0530] "\x09S\xA1\xC6\x8C\xE5\xAB\x18\x8E\x08\xFB\x9B\xEFm\x84\xB5/\x8A3-^k\xF6\x89Y\xB9\x05\xB1\xF6\xA2\xEBF\x0B\xA4B\xCDG#\xE5\xD3\x81\x1C\xF0\xAF\x90QF\xCE\x89" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:44 +0530] "L_\xC8^\xF9\x09\xFA$&\xD3\xABi\xC8\xA4\x01\xB9\xD5T\xE9^\x12i\xC2(\xDDzLs\xDF\xC1\x89A8\x10Z\xDDK\x1FN\xAD@\x97V\x5C\xDDKL\xF4E\xD4e\xE6\x9D\x22\xAAZ\xEB4\x10\xBA\xC0\x82W|\xFC\x1D\xEA\xA4\xE4\xB0mbB&G\x10\xB8l\x97K\xA5\xE8\xA6\xA5\xE0\x83[o\x93\xD4\x5C\xEE\x94\xBE\x05^A\xBAd\x98~\xAEm\xB4W\x9E\xFC\xCE\xBA\x9D~K\xC10\xDE\x02k\xA6\xC3\xE5\xA1\xA6m\xAE{i\xB8\xD0\x8A:\x9E *\x80\xF7\x01\x16<\x8F\xD8a\x8B\x09\xCA\xF8\xF7a\x17\xEDe\x802\x98\xE6p\xC4k\x88\xC0c\xA6\xF2\x19\x03\xD6\x83\xCBl\x8C\xA4pk\xB5\xD5+'5\x9Ae\xF2\xCC\xDE\x93\x87\xCA4\x8CaF\xB3\xFDh_\xFA{\x0E\xD5ci\x8Fs-\xAE\xC8\xDE\xD9\xEE\x0C\xBE\x9B\xA9\x0B\xC8#\xC8\xD5\xCDe\x19\xAF\x9C3\xA5\xAF\x01\xB6N\xF3\xB95[\xF2r \xB9\x83a\xB9\xC4\x8F]\x9DZ` \x9D\xDD\x8A6YYNZ\xE2\x03\x86+\x95Yu#n\xAD\xC1\xA0\x0B7\xCEa\x81R\xCC\x1D\x91\x0E|\x88\xBFY\x11\x8C\xC9_\x8Et\xE7\xBC\xAA\xFF%\x98\xFC{%aX?\x85\xA4\xA1\x13\xF6\xC2\x9D\x8A\x9A\xD5V\xE7\xD4H\xE8\xA3" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:46 +0530] "N\xAE\x13&\xE3v+\xA2&S{-\xDC5k\xD1\x1B\x96:[\x1C\x92J\x18\xFBB\xA4W\x96n\x11\xA0\xE7\x8Af\x92{ya\x0C/\xA0\x0B]" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:46 +0530] "D\xD0\x5C\xCE\x93\x82\xC8z\xBB\xD9l\xCEo\x15w*o\xF2\xF9\xA9\x96\x0Bk\x99\xA1\x1B\xB9\xA5\x1Fg\xC6\x83#\x10.[w!\x0B\xD7i\xD4\xE7\x0B\xCD\x91s\x0E\x22)J\xF3\xF0\xA7\x98\x1E^\x83f\x93\xB9\xCFg\xDBYl\xD5\xBA\xF8d\xA8\xEA\xD6}\xB8\xF8\xFD\x87\xC1\xC3,\x5C\x8C^\x087wN\xD5\xC7\x10\xD7\xECF*ZC6\xDAjK\x80\xBD\xA6%\x1C\xBC\xD6\x1DU\x16\x98\xBBd\x8D\xF6\x02\xA3W7k\xA0\xD9\x87\x9DQ\x8EA\xAA)x\xB6\x9C\xFB?\xC4\xB6\xDB\x0CQ;cL\xF6sr^8\x85\x14\x1D\x95" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:46 +0530] "!\x8CK\xE3\xE9s\x83\xE5@\xECR\xF8K\xA0\xE1\x14\x83%\x88(\x5CIK\xC2\x95z\xDBL%\x865\x12N\xF2\x1E\xBF=f\x9A\xEA\xF4\xAD\xDA\xB3\xA7jB=\x84\x048\xDB\x8E\xA9c:\xA5k\xCC\x12\x983\xC5\xD1Y\xB4\x872\xF6^\x18\xB8u\xCC\xDE\x9C\x9E\xF1\xA6\xD5\x0C\xE9\xDA\xBF\xB7\xE67r\xFA\x08\xF6\x1A\x97\xF4\xA7$\x06\x9C\xE1\x0Cf\xEF\xE7\xD3\x16\x09p\xD5Zk!$\xB6\x7F\xD6\xF8\xAB\xDAh\xF6\xEEl\xC4\x1C\xF6\x16\xDA\xB6\xF7\x1B\xA1\x95\x8Er3\xA0" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:47 +0530] "%^" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:47 +0530] "Z\xB5~\xF5{\x1D\x1A\x05\xAB\xEA\xAF+Awn\xB2\xBA\xDE\xBF7\x82%\x17EWv\xA2\xCFK@g\xC9;/y\xA1|V Xc\xF6\xA4\xB7\x1D\x09\xDE\x10x\xAA\xA9\xB6\xED\xBD4\xBC@\xC0\xAF\x85\x92M$\xBF?\x0F\x22\x84\x95\xFF\xAA\xB50F\xD7:\x04\x05y\xD8\xA8\xE2\xAB\xCB\x18\x1D\xB4 \xEF\xB6o\xED\x8AwyMK\xE2Pn\x87o\x8E\xEF\xEB\x98\x9Dw2r\x88\x10ioI\x80/\xA7+\x03\xD4\xD2w\x8E\xEB\xE4O\x0B\xB5\x1D\xCF\x86\x0B\xEB\x9A" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:47 +0530] "DR\xEEw\xEFO\xDC\xCC\xEE\x90\x91\x90\x8F[x8\xFE\xC66\x16\xCF\xEB\xAA" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:47 +0530] "j_m\x0Em\x19{*s\xD5\xA7\xCA\xEBP\xA2u\xFB9f\x04F\x04X\xDA\xAF\xF3.\xAC\xA2\xCCCq\x9B\x18w\xCFC\x8F\xDD\x0Et\x03\x1A23-\x05\xFD\x82\x14-\x9F\xB9a\xC0\xEA\xFF\xD7:h\xF9\xFE\xA7H!\x81\x09\x16\x10I\x1B\xE9\x167\x06M,\xB7\xDE\xF4\xAF]N\x19!\x1C\xC0\xCAth\x189\xCAa\xED\xF6\xA2dq\xF3W*\x1B\x0B\xB3\x11\xC3\xD9!6\xE2T\x83\xE9\x07gR\xE5\xE0\xBD\xBA\x14\x02\x0C8h\xAA\xBF\x0E\xF7\x11\xE9c\x82\x18\x10\xFD\xE7\x06#0uX\xDA1\xBE\xEC\x99x\x04\xB9H\xB4\x92\xE5N\xE8\xEF\xAB*E\xACy\x9CI\x86z\x1E]\x8D\xD6'\x89\xC77\xE1\x1DQK!\xBB\xA2\x0E\x06\x18\x91\x08\x92sX\xD6K3\x1E2z" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:48 +0530] "\x01I\xDE\xC2,\xBC\x02\xC9J\xD0\xE3\x15\xF6\x1Ap\x9Cd\xE8\x9EAo\xF8\x0E\xE3{D\xCDu\x9FE\xB8\xCD\x85\x98\x90\x22\x0B\x8D\xF3\xBE7\x8F2'K\xFFO`\xF5\xFE\x1FX\xBA\xF0hYq\xC2>\xEFQ\xB8VH\x96\xD9\x03T\xFC" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:48 +0530] "=,W\xDBi\x0F\xE2\xF8\xE0\xBCW2W\xAB\x95h\xE2w\x0F:\xD7\x99\xC7\xA4\xAFe\xC8\x85\xE8\xB6\x82h\xBD*\x12!\x11\x1C\xCEI\xA5\x90h\xEE\xB5\xB4\xAC\x01\xD0\xD9\xCFY^r\x7F\x83x\xD0;\xAE!\xBB\x8F\xA6\xDD\xC7\x9E\x09U\xD4\x1A\x0C[\x17\x03k5\x07\xC0K\xD9\xC2\xEEYOT\xA0\x8Fm\xCB\x04 =\xA7\xE8\xF9P\xC1\xE6\xC4\xFBx\x1F\x8C\xBB\xD6\x90\xC8e\xE1\xE5" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:49 +0530] "b\x85.\xFD=MYk\xB2\x8CU-\xB48^\xB4\x8C\x0E\xF0\xFD\xD1\x13\x01\xB7bV\xD2\x10\x9A_'P\x06\xFDiMq\xE4f-\xCB\x8E]\x82\xBA\xEBf\xBD5\xB0r\xBF\x83\x5Ch\xD3;\xBB<\xB2\xAD\x8D\xA0\x8B\x1A\xCC\x8B\x05-\x88\x11\xAC\xA6|)\xC1\x84\x95\xCF<\x84\xB1{\xA2\x87}\x91O\x14\xC9\x1D\xD2\xAA\xAB" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:50 +0530] "\x17'\x87\xAA\xC9\xDD\x86C\xDF" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:52 +0530] "`L\x90\x95_\xAAwO\xE9\xD7\xCC\x12f5" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:53 +0530] "\x0B\x9C&\x11k\xD7l\xC8\xC3\xDF\xF8\xD1\xB6x\xEC\xCD\xA1:\xFB\x9AgK`\xF6Li\x92\x0C\xCF\x88B\xC7\x84\xA0}.\xFC\x5Cd\x1F\x99\x94\xE9\x94\x84<7\x96#\xD3\xA4a\xE6P\xF1\x8C\xD7\xB4z\xCD\x0E\xDE\x22\x09\x01\xE8B" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:57 +0530] "=\xD6\x06\x93$\x5C\xED\xAD\xCD\xD8\x22A\x19\x8Ey\xDB\x9B\xD2\x9A\xF9\x83c\xD2<\x1A\x10\xD9\xFF\x06\xBD\xC3\x95\x1Ch\x15\xFE\xB8\x93\xB0`$uJ\x970=\xEA\xBB2\xF2\xCF\xF6h\xCD," 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:58 +0530] "iU\xBE\x99<\xDC\x81\xF0\xD6\x22$/\x9EO\xC19g\xA8\x97\xB2i\x91iZ\x11>\xCC^\xC8\xBCP\xE7q\xB3y'\x9C\xE4\xF7\xFE\x1A\xB4\xD9\xA8q\xB0\xDD\xB3\xE7\xE4(\x04E2\x17\x96\x0B\x8A\x99\xAB\xFCN\x13" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:59 +0530] ";m\x17\xD5\x05\xA5Fvr\xA76\x8B4[7N\xB7v\xB2\xC2\xE4\xA3T\x84\xE3@)\x5C\x0C\xAB\xEA\xBCt\xCF9`\xAA\x86\xFB\x02D\x0Cs\xB4\xD9\xA3Or\x9B\x85\xDE\xA5\xAC.\xD0\xD5\x08s\x1C\xDEx\x87\x9E\xD1T\x8AaJ\x9DS\xDB\xAA[}\xE1\x7F\x0E\x9B\x856\xBFg\x82\x9A\xAB\x9C\xB6\xCB\xF5L\x87\xEE\xE9w\xA5x~)\xFE\xEC\x8D\x12\x22~\xA6\xF1?\xC4ccQ\x85\x09\x09Q\x91m\xE8\x96\xE7c\x92B\xAE,\x800\xCB\xDA\xFA\xD9\xFA\xCD\xD2w\xFE\xF7fa\xE6\x8DV\xFFF\x0F\xB8M\x0B\x15D\x9A\xAB8\x8C\x08\xDD\xBB\x10\x1D\xFE\xA1:;=Q0\x8B\xCD\x0BY'P\xBA\xFD\xF3\x92v\xC3\xFE\x1D1T4" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:05:59 +0530] "U\xA0r'$V\xB6\xC3\xC7\x13|y\xA2\xED\xB2WE\xB3\x13\xDA\x1CDd7\xF4S&\xE3\xDCp\xA1IM\xC4\x03AU\xD9\xDF\x0E\xDB\x0F\x88\xB8\xEC\xB8\xCE\x9E#G4\xFDL\xB4\xE4\x0B\x95\x88[[\xE4D1\xAA\x97\xD2\xF9W\x95\xAAA\xD9H\xDD\x07\xF7\x88\x02\xE7T\x8D\xB2\xEA\xCD\xA7\xB2\xEC2\x9D\x8Ae\xAA\xEE\x8Fa2\xFD\xAC\xFFK,_(r\xF7<@\x7F@W@\xFBE\xBB\xAE\xF1\xDE\xAC\xA3\xD6" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:06:00 +0530] "^;k\xF3sa\x13\x10\xFB\x17\x1A\x89=\xEF\xEDd\xA9\x22\xF3B\xB7\xEFQ\x9AE\x96\x19\xD8\xBE\xD5R\xD2\x1DM\x91\xACV\xC1Z&\xA0" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:06:00 +0530] "BF\xBFOo=~\x7F\xEDkE\x10XED\x8A$\x9C\x22\xC5\xCE\xC7\xF2'\xF3\xBC\xBD\xA4\x925?\xC8\xFE\xDBW\x1E\x8DW\xD3\xFB\x85\xF3aM\xA9\xEA\xB4\xF3#\xA0S5\xF04" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:06:00 +0530] "9\xF0\xF2<1o\x84L(\x1CX\x22h,{\xD8\xD5\xD6\xB0\xE8;\x84\xD8\x13wXG\xC7\xD5G\x08\xF2\xAE\xF2\xDAk\xA3Y\xFD\xBA.\xDB\xB8\xF0\xF5j\xFEX\x93-\xD9:*\xFE\xD9\xF5\xB9\x16U\xBF<\x1A6\xF2s\xA5\xFE.7\xED\xBB\x12^g\x07\xB8 \xEF\xEF\xBE0\x1A\xA0\xF8\x93\xC2\xF2)\x1B\xDFbF\x12t\xE5b\x19Y\xEA\x8A\xD8\x1C\xDD@\xEC3Q\xB5\xE9\x8C\xB7\x1F2\xDBs\xBFME%\x13\xAFn\xB3\xD9\x03N\xD4`\xCA\xBA\xCE`\xE4\xEE\xFA\xB5u@\xE6\x18P2\xDA\x14(uS\x89\x0F!\x03 \xEB}\xD4\xED\x89\xD9\x09769\x9D\xF3\x9F\xC4\xE5\x87S\xFD\xE1k\x83H\xF7\xEE\x93\xE2\xD4\xA9\x96\x8E\xA2AE\xEDf\xE5\xFB\xFC\xD2" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:06:00 +0530] "E\x1F\xFDGXN\x8FI\xF8<\xAD~{\xE0T\xD6\x8CK\xFE\x89TR\x9E7\xDB\x05\x8A\x0FJ\xD9\xBD\xB5\xBBl\xB5\x06Z\xB5F3]\x90\xBF`\x91\xC7\xCE\x12Ak\xCEt\x95\xB0\xA7\xA5\x95e\xCA\xEBV)\xC0B\xC8;\xD6\xD4\x86Fv\xBF\xC8\x0B\xC2\x0C\x9A\xF6~\xAFC\xE7\xF1\x92E\xA9E\xE5\xBC\xA7\x1B\xE4pAU\xB2U\xA0\xA8\xC1V" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:06:03 +0530] "|\x85\x87\x91dn)\xD1\x83\xE6a\x5CvA\xDB\xE9\xB6I9b\xA35\xCD\xED\xECR\x7F\x91i\x99!,B\x8E\xCF\xD4\xF9\xDD(x\xCB\x9A\xEC\xDEF\xE0" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:06:05 +0530] "\x11\xCFQ\x86\xEBL!\x9C\xFF!\xDE\xCD\x92\xDF.\xDB~\x7F\xCE\xF0\x9A\xDA\x99F\xCA\xB1\xDA\x8C\x15\xDD\x0E\x9B\xA0\xC6u(\xB4\x04s\xB4\x0B\x05\xDF\xEB(\x1E\x85'\x7F\xB5Q\xEF\xD8\xE7\xA6l\x5C\xC1\x16o.G\x193AwxO\xD6\x09mks\x17\xB6\xDE\x98\xF3Rt\xC9\xD3\xF6\xE71~L\x0CA-\x11\xA8\xF9(q\xE4\x15=\xBD\x8C\x92\xC4\x94s\x0E%\x0E\xB0,\x84]\xBE\xF6mn\x0B\xD2L\xDC-\xDC\xF5\xC3h\x85J2\xE2\xAA\x90\x80g\x22\x0C\x19\xA0\xE0/\x12}\xE1pA/\xF1\x01\xBD\x8DG\xFC\xE9[47\x12&\x22\x91\xDE*\x94\x18\xFA\x85\xCC\x8Blgo" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:06:06 +0530] "\x11\x0F\xDC6\xA8\x83\x8A\xCE\xB4+u\x0BSx\xFE\x9A\x90J\x0B[\xDC:\x9D\x9E\x8E\x19\xDC\xC8'`\x89P\x14\xB3Qyy]O?\xC0\x15\x89\xEC\xF4_\x5C\xF6\x1A\xC2\xDD\x133'%t!\x91z\xFA\xEB\xDA\xFDLkLK \xC5\xCEa\xC0(\x8C\xDD\xEBS\xA5g\xE1[f\x22\xD5\xFF\xF8#c\x94#\xF8\x13\xA6\xCAi\xD5\x82,b" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:06:07 +0530] "L\x93\xA6\xCE\xA8\x1C\xE8\xBB;\xADPc\x15\x5C\xE0u\x91\xBAH\xA6\x0C\xED\x94\xD9\x95\x1En\xDA?p]\xF0^\x22U3\xBB<\xD0l:\xAEn" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:06:07 +0530] "\x19\xFD\xAD\x00i\xC4\x04+\xE5\x96I]V\x1E\x9D\xAA\x1ADW3}~\xE6\xED\xAE\xDE1\x10\xF7\xD5\x13\x0E\xBB\x8A\x84\x8D\xFF\xBB\xDB.\xEF\xBD\x80;\x8C\x9A:\x01\xFA\x15\x9B\x93\xBEk\xEB\x1F\x143&\xD2\xD6*l\x0B\xA6C\x8B\xBB\xD2\x17\x97\xCD5\xB5\x96\xE8\xEC{\xA3\x84\xEE\xE7\xCEV\x91\xCD\x0C\xE9\xFD\xEB\xC2g\x16\xA8}\xE7\xACaZ\xF9\xDC|\x01h\xD1\xCE\xE8\x22r\x9C\x1AW\x04\xE25&@VOY\x89i\x8D/\xF7\x9FE^\xB0\x5C\xA7f\xB9\xFAo2`\xED=\x11\xFC\x89}\x90\x98\xD8\x0FKv\xA1\x96!01\x9D\xCC\x9C\xDF@,F\xFD\xC2\x8F!\xC1Y\x84)\x5CY \x22\xAD\xD2\x94d\xD8F\x16\x9D\xE2\xD1\x81\xEC\x16\xF6\x8E5\x09\xCA.\x8F=(\xC5:d\xED\xA4\x03U\xD5\xC5,\xC1?@\xE0\x09\x8Ft" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:06:09 +0530] "B\x8E|\x1FR0Z\xF8i\xACd\xCA\x98\x90\xF6F\x0C\xE5\xB9\xF6\x96X\xE2\xF3<\x04!\xD9\x13\xA5`#\xD1;\x03%j\x7F\x88\xB6\xE5 \xF6;\xF1F9\xE2\xD3%\x99\xDD\x1C7@}U\xD0'w\xB2" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:06:09 +0530] "\x14G\x8F\xE9Yc\x1DG\xDC\x9178F*\x18\xC1\x5C\xFBQ\x03VpR\xDCA\xEEk\xE9\xFA\xD5\xB8mQTz3\x9F\x0F\xD0F\xA6\x9E;]\xAA\xF52\x06,=\xCD\x1F&\xAE\xB8\xD1\xA2\x97#\xD3\xB3\x22@!\x0B\x95\xCD\x98\x96\x94,5^\x87\xB5\xB4\x15\x98\xCF%\xE4\xA2\x16\xF4L\xFA\xE25\xA7\xE4\x05\xC0N\x1F\xD3\x82\x9Eg\xAA\xA4[\x95\xF7}\xFF\xAA\x1D\xCA\x7F\x85\xD2^\xA0\xC1\x9D\xC9\x9C\xFB\xA6\xF8\xFF\xCD\x81\xD4Vlw\xCF@\xF3\xF7r\xE9\xD85S\xF5\xF6\xDDSn\xE9\x94}Z\xA3\x073\xEB`v\xA3%\xB0\xE3\xCF*\x9D\xA6\xF4\xB6\xCC\x19G" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:06:09 +0530] "O\xE1+\xCA\xF3\xCBr\xE1<\x0F?a\x06x\xF3Z\x86\x80e!L/\x85\xCF\x9DZ\x04\xE1:\x1A\x08|\x18\xC1\xF9\x1Es$\xFB\xA0\xE3\xD5\xFB\x80c\xD2\x92Tf" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:06:09 +0530] ";J\xC0\xA8p%\x1B\xF5wc\xEEj\x1B\xD6\xE2C+8RZ\x8A\x832\xE9o\xC5\xA9\xDEBY\xF4\x85\xC4T\xF3\x1C\xF2\xCDU\x9DIx\x1F\xA7\xFA\xA8r \xB48\xA5R\xA2\xB9\x8A\x8D\xA3\xF2\x17>\xB6\xB1\x1B\xA6'\xE0\x81\xB6jMN" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:06:10 +0530] "g\x07\xD1@Y\x87\xD9b\x11#2\x0FG\x90\x11\x0B\xDCj\xEA\xE4\xB3\xF0\xC5\x99\xB8,\x12\xB3\xC8\x01<\xED\xE7\x14\x1C\xE1/*i>\x0E" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:06:10 +0530] "b\xBC\xEE\x14\x10C\xF7C\xCF\x83\xFE\xE3\x15g\x22\xC1\x83\x92\xD9\x14\x9F\x85\xA1c\xE5\xA7\xDF\xC6\xCA\x96n\x22\xB5sm\xB1\x07\xA2\xA0\x9A\xC1\x9E2\x8A\x02*}\x9F:X\x91\xD6\x95\x88\xDE\x9Ev\x1D\xA8\x9A\xAF\xA9\x15\xE8k%\xEAC\x1C*\xCB\x8E]I\xE2\x96\x86:'@\xE7qY\x0EU\xA4\xFD\x19\xEC\x22\xC6-X\xB9\x0C\xB3+p\xC7\xB0\xD9\x13\xE6A\xB73\x98\xA9NN\xDF\xA7\xB6S\xB5\xF3\x93=\xA3\xE5\xB6+\x96\x92\xD3<\x0E\xFB\x0F\xFD\x00\xA4$\xA8\x1F\x7Fq\xAD\xA70\xCF318\xE6\xC4.g\xC9o\xF8L1\xCF\xC7<\xDC\x15!\x8F\xAB\x06\xFE\x7F\x86d\xBA\xDA\xCA2\x86\xC3HK\xED\xE0v\x83>\x80\x1B+\xB9\x10MC\xEC\xD0{$W`P\xF04\xBA\xDC\x82\xF2\x96\x8E" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:06:11 +0530] "L~t\xF2{\x9D\xD9=\xE2l\xE0\x0E\xE2\xEC\xFDYE\x8AT\xCEU\x05\xDF\xBFXI\x98\x9A\xB14\xD1\xC0b&\xF83\xCA\xE0\xF5\xC3\x8Fy\x13\x90\xA1\x80J\xB4r\x88\x0F.\xF2\xA9\x1A\xCD-K\xC9\xF7\xE8\xFA\x0C\xB3\xF2\x06F\x02\xA1\x80\x91\x861$X\xA0\xA6J\xD0R\xE7\x86\xB6V/\x0F\x84w@\x93&6\xBFb\x5C\xFA\xFF\x8D4\x8A\xBCK\xEE0\x12\xBBX}\xE4ZRb9H!\x83\xABK\xDEa\x88Q\x19d\xD2\xD0X\xB0Hr\xC1\xCF_i\x12\xAD\x02p\xAA\xEF\x05t\xB3\xC8\xB6ct\xF2\x96t\xEC\x10(\xCFD\x0E\xEB\xA0\xC1\xE3c\x8E\x85\x8D\xF5\xA3Bm\xE3\x95\xC6z:\xBF\xE9\xB1}\xF7x\x86\x93\xE6\x1Dk\xAC\xB2t\x5C)\xBD\xD3Tm\xDFn\x94\x85\x14\xBC \xE8V\xB8\xC1\xEF\xFE\xB9f\xE4zo\x99\x8BA\xCD\xC9\x0E\xA5jY\x84\xB5\x1C?.+\xFC\x89 \x9A\xA6\xEE\x82w\x8D/\x9B(-\x169 \xB0\x05[\xE9#\xC3\xDD" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:06:11 +0530] "iM\x1E\xCA\x80\xE9p\xE4\xCD\xF6}y\x04\xF4\x16\xF9\xD6\xF7\x0E\x0E\xBD]2l\x8C.." 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:06:11 +0530] "`?E\x06\xC1|F\x8D\xD2\xDFG\x5C\xD0P\x82\x9F\x80\xE0\xC7l\xD70" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:06:12 +0530] "_\x98\x90\xFF\x09\x1Fk\x15\xE5$)i\x5C_\x94$\x1B\x10H9\x00d\xE8\xFFD\x0F\xF0\x8C\xD7$\xBCU4:Uv\xC2\xEE\xF4o\xB3\xF3" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:06:12 +0530] "5\x8Dm^\x9Eh\x8F\xBCv\x8D\xA7\x9B|\xCB" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:06:12 +0530] "v*^\xEFU\x8F\xC1\xFC\x13\x95\xBE\xA1q\x9A\xB0F\x1C\xB4\xE8\xC3\xDB\xE32\xB5" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:06:16 +0530] "t\x09\xAE#~\xB2" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:06:17 +0530] "s\xE7\x16\xEF\xD0I\xA7\x01\x1C\xEEO\xAA\xA4\xBF\xAD8\xBC3@\xA1\xEC\xAB\xE4\x9F\xB5\x14\xDD_\xB1\x02\x18Z\xEC\xD2aw\xB0\xC7wO\xA3Nx\xED\xBE\x05\xB5\xD8Cj\xFDRF\xC7\x5C\xA1\xB2\xF8\xE1V\xE2\x92\xCB6\xE4\xA3\xB8\x1B\xEA(V\xD4l\xCB\x9C\xBF\xDE\xA3\xC1B\x9C\x00!\xE3\x08\x03\xDC`{\xEDB\xBC\xF7\xA56\xBE%\x8F\xC7\xA5s\xD9b\x93\x1Ch(\xDBK\xC1\xAA\x9B\xE9\xFFST\xD8C\xA4i\xBA\xAD\xB9[\xAF\xEF" 400 166 "-" "-"
|  151.239.55.4 - - [13/Nov/2021:16:06:17 +0530] "5\x97\x05C\x12\x8D{]\xD4fE\x7F\xEA\xA7s\x84\xB0\xB4}/\x91\x99\xAB.n\x88Hc\xFAp\x86E\x93i\xC9g\xE8\xB4S\x08wL2q\xF7S\xD6`\xA4\xA7\xFF\x08\xD1\x1AC\x89+\x91\xB5\xCB\x0B\xA6>k\x07\xC9j\x9F\x89Q\xDDgt@\xF5:\xAE\x19\xD8\xDA\x1Dy\x97\xF0\xEF[n\x9CJ\x0BhP\xFDe\xC6\xBDq\xC5\x9C\xC4-4\xDC\xB8\xBD\x045\xFDP\x15\xB2\x1E\xE7R\xA6-\xF8c\x11\xB6h\xD0\xECE<\xD4>\x8Dz\xECt\xC0" 400 166 "-" "-"
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the fail2ban filters you are hoping to improve.

Answer (score 2):

Your `failregex` is not accurate (moreover it is vulnerable) because it is searching and can find `400` literally everywhere and not as a response code only.
The begin anchor (`^`) is only working for `<HOST>` tag and stops to operate hereafter due to catch-all `.*` and not end-anchored, because `.*$` is not an anchor at all, so ultimately the regex is unanchored from both sides, what is always bad, because:

- it's vulnerable in sense of accuracy (e. g. false positives)
- it makes parsing extremely slow (especially on some long messages)

Also you don't need extra filter for such simple thing, you can set it directly in jail, so this would be fully enough in your `jail.local`:

```
[ban-400]
logpath = ...
filter =
port = 80,443
failregex = ^<ADDR> \S+ \S+(?: \[\])? "[^"]*" 400\s
enabled = true
```

This `failregex` is accurate and as fast as possible (it finds 400 only as response code).

**Remark:** *(nginx is not affected)*
If a quote-character can be also enclosed between quotes as escaped value like `\"` (*nginx escapes it as `\x22`, see excerpt, so it is rather escaped as hex value and `"` should not occur at all*), you could replace `"[^"]*"` with `"(?:[^"]*|(?:[^"\\]*|\\.)*)"`, which can be a bit slower than former.

Also please note the [fail2ban :: wiki :: Best practice](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/wiki/Best-practice).

Comment: This explains performance and false positives, but I read the question more as a problem with false negatives. In any case, the question should be improved to clarify.